# How to make an Ajax Call Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What i need:

- i  need to send ajax call using javascript.
- i have used jquery for ajax call.

Jquery code:

```
var mobile = $("#mobiledropdown".attr("value");
url = window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1 ? document.URL + "&asyn=1" : document.URL + "?asyn=1", jQuery.support.cors = !0, $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: mobile,
cache: !1,
dataType: "json",
crossDomain: !0,
success: function(t) {
    if (t.industry.length > 0) {
        industry = "{{ page_param.page.industry_url }}";

        for (var e = 0; e < t.industry.length; e++)

        $("#industry").append("" != industry && t.industry[e].industry_url == industry ? "<option value=" + t.industry[e].industry_url + " selected >" + t.industry[e].name + " </option>" : "<option value=" + t.industry[e].industry_url + ">" + t.industry[e].name + " </option>")

    }

    else $("#industry").addClass("off").css({
        "background-color": "#f4f4f4",
        "border-color": "#eaeaea",
        color: "#ccc"
    }), $("#industry").attr("disabled", "");
    if (t.country.length > 0) {
        country = "{{ page_param.page.country_url }}";
        for (var e = 0; e < t.country.length; e++) $("#country").append("" != country && t.country[e].country_url == country ? "<option value=" + t.country[e].country_url + " selected >" + t.country[e].text + " </option>" : "<option value=" + t.country[e].country_url + ">" + t.country[e].text + " </option>")
    } else $("#country").addClass("off"), $("#country").attr("disabled", "");
    if (t.city.length > 0) {
        city = "{{ page_param.page.city_url }}";
        for (var e = 0; e < t.city.length; e++) $("#city").append("" != city && t.city[e].city_url == city ? "<option value=" + t.city[e].city_url + " selected >" + t.city[e].text + " </option>" : "<option value=" + t.city[e].city_url + ">" + t.city[e].text + " </option>")
    } else $("#city").addClass("off").css({
        "background-color": "#f4f4f4",
        "border-color": "#eaeaea",
        color: "#ccc"
    }), $("#city").attr("disabled", "");
    if (t.type.length > 0) {
        type = "{{ page_param.page.event_type }}";
        for (var e = 0; e < t.type.length; e++) 1 == t.type[e].entityType && $("#shows").append("" != type && t.type[e].entityType == type ? "<option value=" + t.type[e].entityType + " selected > Trade Shows </option>" : "<option value=" + t.type[e].entityType + "> Trade Shows </option>"), 2 == t.type[e].entityType && $("#shows").append("" != type && t.type[e].entityType == type ? "<option value=" + t.type[e].entityType + " selected > Conferences </option>" : "<option value=" + t.type[e].entityType + "> Conferences </option>")
    }
    $("#shows").append("<option value= 3 > Venues </option>"), $("#shows").append("<option value= 4> Organizers </option>"), $("#shows").append("<option value= 5> Top100 </option>")
}
});
```

- Javascript  ajax call is not working
  code

  ```
   window.onload = function() {
   var mobile =         document.getElementById('mobiledropdown').getAttribute('value');

  url = window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1 ? document.URL + "&asyn=1" : document.URL + "?asyn=1"
  function loadFilters() {


      var xmlhttp;

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
          // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
             if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
             {

                          if (xmlhttp.t.industry.length > 0) {
                          industry = "{{ page_param.page.industry_url }}";

                          for (var e = 0; e < xmlhttp.t.industry.length; e++)

                          $("#industry").append("" != industry && xmlhttp.t.industry[e].industry_url == industry ? "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.industry[e].industry_url + " selected >" + xmlhttp.t.industry[e].name + " </option>" : "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.industry[e].industry_url + ">" + xmlhttp.t.industry[e].name + " </option>")

                          }

                          else $("#industry").addClass("off").css({
                          "background-color": "#f4f4f4",
                          "border-color": "#eaeaea",
                          color: "#ccc"
                          }), $("#industry").attr("disabled", "");
                          if (xmlhttp.t.country.length > 0) {
                          country = "{{ page_param.page.country_url }}";
                          for (var e = 0; e < xmlhttp.t.country.length; e++) $("#country").append("" != country && xmlhttp.t.country[e].country_url == country ? "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.country[e].country_url + " selected >" + xmlhttp.t.country[e].text + " </option>" : "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.country[e].country_url + ">" + xmlhttp.t.country[e].text + " </option>")
                          } else $("#country").addClass("off"), $("#country").attr("disabled", "");
                          if (xmlhttp.t.city.length > 0) {
                          city = "{{ page_param.page.city_url }}";
                          for (var e = 0; e < xmlhttp.t.city.length; e++) $("#city").append("" != city && xmlhttp.t.city[e].city_url == city ? "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.city[e].city_url + " selected >" + xmlhttp.t.city[e].text + " </option>" : "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.city[e].city_url + ">" + xmlhttp.t.city[e].text + " </option>")
                          } else $("#city").addClass("off").css({
                          "background-color": "#f4f4f4",
                          "border-color": "#eaeaea",
                          color: "#ccc"
                          }), $("#city").attr("disabled", "");
                          if (xmlhttp.t.type.length > 0) {
                          type = "{{ page_param.page.event_type }}";
                          for (var e = 0; e < xmlhttp.t.type.length; e++) 1 == xmlhttp.t.type[e].entityType && $("#shows").append("" != type && xmlhttp.t.type[e].entityType == type ? "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.type[e].entityType + " selected > Trade Shows </option>" : "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.type[e].entityType + "> Trade Shows </option>"), 2 == xmlhttp.t.type[e].entityType && $("#shows").append("" != type && xmlhttp.t.type[e].entityType == type ? "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.type[e].entityType + " selected > Conferences </option>" : "<option value=" + xmlhttp.t.type[e].entityType + "> Conferences </option>")
                          }
                          $("#shows").append("<option value= 3 > Venues </option>"), $("#shows").append("<option value= 4> Organizers </option>"), $("#shows").append("<option value= 5> Top100 </option>")

             }
             else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                alert('There was an error 400')
             }
             else {
                 alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
             }
          }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET", "mobile", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
  }
    };
  ```

HTML element

```
  <span id="mobiledropdown" value="{{-p|raw}}" onload="loadFilters();"></span>
```

Problem

- xhr request is not working.
- im new in ajax using javascript.
- jquery ajax call is working fine but ajax using javascript is not working.
- i want javascript how could send json in datatype , cross domain in javascript.
- any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: Format your code, indentations and stuff. It's really a spaghetti, and I really don't know if code like `industry = "{{ page_param.page.industry_url }}";` might help to help

Comment: Also, why don't you use jQuery's `$.ajax` ?

Comment: I don't know if you understood me. Remove all nonsense stuff that are not related to AJAX. Use console to spot possible errors, than come back here with the minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: im working on page speed so i dont want include juqery lib that why i switch to javscript

Comment: OK fine, it's not that hard to make an AJAX call in pure JavaScript, just I really don't think we need stuff like `$("#city").attr("disabled", "");` to help you.

Comment: where is your symphony controller ?

Comment: Why you want to do that when jquery one is working?

Comment: im working in page speed juqery latency is more then javscript

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false, // In your code you're waiting the req. I dont know why.
    url: "http://someUrl", // Remote URL at which you sending the request
    success: function(response) {
        // Here you can handle the response from the server.
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // Here you handle if the HTTP request fails (if status is > 299)
    }
})
```

If you just miss to set `async` the default value is `true`, so it will send the request, and your code will continue executing. After the response is available, the `success` function will be called. I recommend to use `async: true` or just don't define it in the options. In case you don't try to access the response data outside of success function, you do not need it.

You can use `$` instead of jQuery in case this varable is not overridden by other library or other code.

Inside the jQuery object you can put many other options for caching, request, [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

You can replace all base javascript's XMLHttpRequest functionality with `$.ajax({})`

You can use shorthand method `$.get()`

In your case:

```
$.get('mobile', function(response) {
    // Here you can handle the response when it come from the server.
})
```